# template template parameter that is counted as one single parameter

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates, template-templates

In the code below, the class template uses one parameter but the function template uses two if the template argument is a template. This is ok when using type deduction but odd when using explicit template instantiation.

Is is possible to write the template template parameter as one single parameter?

This question is linked to [function overload matching template template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565509/function-overload-matching-template-template)

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct C
{
    C (T i)
    {
        std::cout << "simple" << std::endl;
    }
};
template <template<typename TT> class FF, typename TT>
struct C <FF<TT> >          // (1)
{
    C (FF<TT> i)
    {
        std::cout << "template" << std::endl;
    }
};
template <typename T>
void F (T i)
{
    std::cout << "simple" << std::endl;
}

// two template arguments FF and TT.
// Anyway to write this so that the argument count is one?
template <template<typename TT> class FF, typename TT>
void F (FF<TT> i)
{
    std::cout << "template" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
struct R
{
    T x;
};
int main()
{
        R<int>     r;
        C<R<int> >{r};      // prints 'template', as expected
        F<R<int> >(r);      // prints 'simple',  probably not what you think
        F<R,int  >(r);      // prints 'template' as expected but 
}
```

EDIT:

I came to the conclusion that the question is not a good one because if there where a one parameter syntax, the overload resolution would still pick the wrong function. This comes as a surprise to me but here is the code that proves it (same code as before except one template function overload that changed):

EDIt2: added a further print in the main skipping the explicit template specification.

**EDIT3: The code below is nonsense**. I made a mistake as @DyP pointed out correctly. I am calling `void F(R<R<T>>)` in the explicit case and not `void F(R<T>)` .

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct R
{
    T x;
};
template <typename T>
struct C
{
    C (T i)
    {
        std::cout << "simple" << std::endl;
    }
};
template <template<typename TT> class FF, typename TT>
struct C <FF<TT> >          // (1)
{
    C (FF<TT> i)
    {
        std::cout << "template" << std::endl;
    }
};
template <typename T>
void F (R<T> i)
{
    std::cout << "template" << i.x << std::endl;
}
template <typename T>
void F (T i)
{
    std::cout << "simple" << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
        R<int>     r;
        C<R<int> >{r};      // prints 'template', as expected
        F<R<int> >(r);      // prints 'simple',  probably not the expected overload
        F         (r);      // prints 'template', now overload resolution works. Strange.
}
```

Comment: I'm ashamed to admit it, but I have *never* understood template template parameters.  Eventually I gave up trying.

Comment: It boils down to this fact : because function template doesn't support partial specialization, so the *kind* of pattern matching which you enjoy with class template, is not there in case of function template.

Comment: I think it's possible using SFINAE; both functions would take the same arguments, but one accepts non-template type whereas the other accepts template specializations.

Comment: The classical way is to make the function forwards to struct implementation (i.e: `template <class T>void F(T t) { C<T>()(t); }` by using `operator()` instead of constructor).

Comment: The reason why your amended version prints `simple` is because you explicitly specified the template parameter (explicitly specifying template parameters should only be used where required, as a rule of thumb). The overloads the call selects from are `void F<R<int>>(R<R<int>>);` (which would print "template") and `void F<R<int>>(R<int>);` (which prints "simple"). Only the second one is viable.

Comment: @DyP. Yes, i said that in my initial question already. But this is example code. Imagine, you have no function parameter from which you can deduce. I have enhanced the main function in the second example. Strange that the overload resolution depends on where the compiler retrieves the type information (via resolution or explicit specification). I strongly suspect now that function template instantiation with explicit types is an evil anti-pattern.

Comment: It's not the fault of overload resolution here. By the time overload resolution kicks in, type deduction (and substitution) has already been done. Type deduction will *not* be done for explicitly specified template arguments. Your new call `F(r)` will result in the two overloads `void F<int>(R<int>);` (the "template" version) and `void F< R<int> >(R<int>);` (the "simple" version), and overload resolution will select the more specialized one ("template").

Comment: Argh, in my previous comment I meant (via deduction or explicit specification). Why should the overload resolution be different for explicit types or deduced types? That does not go into my head. It is especially strange if overload resolution kicks in after type deduction as you are saying.

Comment: The overload resolution as an algorithm doesn't work differently here, but its input data is different for the two cases. For the explicitly specified `F< R<int> >(r)`, the set of overloads (= functions found with the name `F`, for which type deduction and substitution have been performed) is `void F(R< R<int> >);` (i.e. the function `void F(R<T>)` with `T = R<int>`) and `void F(R<int>);` (the function `void F(T)` with `T = R<int>`). Note you don't specify the parameter type, but the template parameter; therefore the first function becomes `F(R<R<int>>)`.

Comment: @DyP: Ups, you are right, I see my mistake. I was calling `F(R<R<int>>)` indeed. That is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SFINAE:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct is_template_with_one_param
: std::false_type
{};

template<template<class> class TT, class T>
struct is_template_with_one_param< TT<T> >
: std::true_type
{};


#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if< not is_template_with_one_param<T>{}, void >::type
F (T i)
{
    std::cout << "simple" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if< is_template_with_one_param<T>{}, void >::type
F (T i)
{
    std::cout << "template" << std::endl;
}
```

usage example:

```
template <typename T>
struct R
{
    T x;
};
int main()
{
        F(R<int>{});
        F(42);
}
```

Alternatively, consider [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164045/template-template-parameter-that-is-counted-as-one-single-parameter#comment28349838_19164045).

Comment: N.B. one of those overload could also be written as `template<class T, class... TT> void F(T i, TT...);`

Comment: This is a correct answer. But it is a bit a workaround so I will wait a bit before marking it as the correct answer. I would like to know if there is a natural "one parameter" syntax. But I am afraid there is none which is why everybody is using class templates with static functions as workaround, which is actually nicer then using SFINAE.

Comment: @PatrickFromberg As Nawaz said, the alternative is explicit specialization, like `template<> void F< R<int> >(R<int>);`. Partial specialization of function templates isn't allowed; if it was, one could write `template<template<class> class TT, class T> void F< TT<T> > (TT<T>);`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct C
{
    C (T i)
    {
        std::cout << "simple" << std::endl;
    }
};
template <template<typename TT> class FF, typename TT>
struct C <FF<TT> >          // (1)
{
    C (FF<TT> i)
    {
        std::cout << "template" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
void F (T i)
{
    C<T> x(i);
}

template <typename T>
struct R
{
    T x;
};
int main()
{
        R<int>     r;
        F(r);
        F(4);
}
```

Comment: As stated in the question, type deduction works fine. It is the explicit instantiation where the issue arises.

Comment: @Patrick Fromberg: `F<R<int>>(r)` and `F<int>(4)` will work fine too.